# How to identify renamed files on linux?

Tags: linux, find, rename

I am using the 'find' command to identify modified files. But I've noticed that my method only identifies content-modified files and new files. It does not identify files where the only change was a rename. Is there a way to use 'find' to identify renamed files? If not, is there some other linux command that can be used for this?

Here is my current method for identifying changed files going back roughly one month (this method does NOT identify renamed files):

```
$ touch --date "2017-09-10T16:00:00" ~/Desktop/tmp

$ find ~/Home -newer ~/Desktop/tmp -type f > modified-files
```

Comment: The answer to this question explains the difference between mtime, atime, and ctime: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104799/what-counts-as-a-file-modification-or-change and illustrates the use of "stat" to see inode attributes.

Comment: And the answer to this question demonstrates the use of "find" with ctime: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170990/find-command-with-ctime-0-for-testing

Answer (score 0):

You should replace option `-newer` with `\( -newer -o -cnewer \)` in order to catch modifications to file metadata as well.